# Mysql SSL unsupported protocol error

Tags: macos, mysql, ssl

Since a couple days I cannot connect to several mysql instances when using SSL. I am quite sure it's a problem on my machine, since colleagues and production servers don't have this issue. In both my Python clients and the `mysql` command line client I get an error.

See this example when using the `mysql` CLI:

```
$ mysql -h blablabla.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com -D dbname -U username
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol
```

I think there is something wrong with my SSL settings, openssl, certificates, ... Well as you can guess from the options, I don't understand enough about this to pinpoint the problem :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. As a quick workaround, could you try whether this flag: `--ssl-mode=DISABLED` helps (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/65916427/881191)? (Check out the other answers too, they could be useful.)

Comment: Yeah, that works! The only thing is my python client (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient) doesn't seem to have the disable option, also it seems not the best option to disable SSL completely of course.

Comment: Ah, that is not true. I can also disable it with a new version of `mysqlclient` using `ssl_mode='DISABLED'` as param to `MySQLdb.connect`. Still not ideal, but at least I can connect. Thanks for the pointer to the stackoverflow question :)

Comment: I'm glad the workaround works, but I definitely agree: there must be a better way of solving this. In the linked post there are other answers, you may want to try them...